# Windows 10 downgrade to Windows 7 interrupted; stuck in boot loop

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-10

I was attempting to downgrade from Windows 10 back to Windows 7, but the process got stuck, and after several hours I forced shutdown.

When I reboot, the blue HP screen shows, then the screen goes black, the HP screen shows, and it continues in this loop.

I can access the command prompt through a Windows 10 install disc, but so far my attempts of fixing the boot protocols have been unsuccessful.

I run the command `bootrec /RebuildBcd`, and it finds a Windows installation, however when I prompt it to add the installation to the boot list it says `The requested system device cannot be found.`

I suspect Windows itself may have become corrupted, and I wonder if there is any means of fixing that, or recovering my personal files

Comment: can you see your files? Navigate to them in DOS etc,. I would concentrate on recovering data first, then probably format the drive and rebuild

Comment: I can navigate in my folders, so I assume the files are intact. I have a 1tb external drive with nothing important on it, is there a means of copying the c drive to that?

Comment: yes, several ways, probably the easiest is to get a hirens boot cd and boot to mini xp which gives you an easy to use interface to copy your files with. Google Hirens boot cd and download it and either burn it to cd or make it into a bootable USB drive. I'm not advertising for Hirens, it's free software, just that it's the one I'm familiar with, Probably there are others.

Comment: once you have your data safe, format the drive and rebuild the computer. When rebuilding check your BIOS settings are compatible with Windows 7 or 10 whichever you choose.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, thanks a lot. If you want to put all this as an answer, I can give you the well deserved reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can navigate to your files in DOS etc,. then your files are still ok. I would concentrate on recovering data first, then probably format the drive and rebuild.

There are several ways you can recover your data, probably the easiest is to get a hirens boot cd and boot to mini xp which gives you an easy to use interface to copy your files with. Google Hirens boot cd and download it and either burn it to cd or make it into a bootable USB drive. I'm not advertising for Hirens, it's free software, just that it's the one I'm familiar with, Probably there are others.

You could also remove your hard drive and use another machine to retrieve the data, either by plugging it in directly, or using a SATA to USB adapter.

Once you have your data safe, format the drive and rebuild the computer. When rebuilding check your BIOS settings are compatible with Windows 7 or 10 whichever you choose.

Comment: Much obliged, I was able to recover all of my data, all that's left to do is format the drive. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad its working out for you